# Which deep learning model can classify categories which are not mutually exclusive

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning

Examples : I have a sentence in job description : "Java senior engineer in UK ".

I want to use a deep learning model to predict it as 2 categories : `English`  and `IT jobs`. If i use traditional classification model, it only can predict 1 label with `softmax` function at last layer . Thus, i can use 2 model neural networks to predict "Yes"/"No" with both categories, but if we have more categories, it is too expensive . So do we have any deeplearning or machine learning model to predict 2 or more categories at same time ?

"Edit" : With 3 labels by traditional approach , it will be encoded by [1,0,0] but in my case, it will be encoded by [1,1,0] or [1,1,1]

Example : if we have 3 labels, and a sentence may be fit with all of these labels. So if output from softmax function is [0.45 , 0.35 , 0.2 ] we should classify it into 3 labels or 2 labels , or may be one ?

The main problem when we do it is : what is good threshold to classify into 1, or 2 , or 3 labels ?

Comment: Use two models?

Comment: As i said, it is too expensive if we have 10 - 20 categories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have n different categories which can be true at the same time, have n outputs in your output layer with a sigmoid activation function. This will give each output a value between 0 and 1 independently.

Your loss function should be the mean of the negative log likelihood of the outputs. In tensorflow, this is:

```
linear_output = ...  # the output layer before applying activation function
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    logits=linear_output, labels=correct_outputs))
output = tf.sigmoid(linear_output)  # 0 to 1 for each category
```

Comment: sorry, can you explain more ? i still can not understand your idea. Usually, number of output nodes = number of categories , so how do you change it ?

Comment: @voxter You have 2 categories and 2 output nodes so that is still correct. You just apply sigmoid activation instead of softmax.

Comment: ex: we have 3 labels : If we use soft max function : output will be [0.45 , 0.35 , 0.2 ] (Sum is always equal 1 ).
If we use signmoid :output will be [ 0.8 , 0.8 , 0.6 ] > can we choose it is categorized into 2 labels or 3 labels ?

Comment: If you have 2 categories, you should have 2 outputs. If you have 3 categories, you should have 3 outputs. The sigmoid will give each one a value between 0 and 1 which is the probability for that category. Unlike softmax, the values do not sum to one so any number of them can be true (close to 1) at the same time.